# R Shiny DateRangeInput help to select dates

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(dateRangeInput(inputId = "turkat$time",format = "yyyy-mm- 
dd",min=min(turkat$time),max = max(turkat$time),start="1990-01- 
01",separator="-" ),
            headerPanel("Earthquake"),

            mainPanel(plotOutput("map"))

)

server <- function(input, output) {
 turkat <-  reactive({
 turkat[,turkat$time]
 })
 output$map<-renderPlot({ par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 3.1, 2.1))

    plot(turkiye, axes=TRUE,ylim=c(38,42),xlim=c(26,42))
    points(turkat$longitude,turkat$latitude,pch=15,cex="0.5",col="green")

     })
   }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to draw map of earthquakes between the user selected dates with R shiny. I am new to it and keep taking this error. Also I want to plot it according to magnitudes by using cex argument. How can I do it?

> Error in label %AND% tags$label(class = "control-label", `for` =
>   controlName,  :    argument "label" is missing, with no default

thanks in advance

Comment: The way you are initializing the `dateRangeInput` and calling it in the server is incorrect. Please take some time to look over the examples laid out here https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/dateRangeInput.html

Comment: Thanks Chabo. I get it now . However I could not load my data properly and getting this error. " undefined colums select"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput("turkat_time",format = "yyyy-mm-dd",min=min(turkat$time),max = max(turkat$time),start="1990-01-01",separator="-" ),
  headerPanel("Earthquake"),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("map"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  myturkat <- reactive({
    turkat[,input$turkat_time]
  })

  output$map <- renderPlot({ 
    req(myturkat())

    par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 3.1, 2.1))
    plot(myturkat(), axes=TRUE,ylim=c(38,42),xlim=c(26,42))
    points(myturkat()$longitude,myturkat()$latitude,pch=15,cex="0.5",col="green")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: provide all the relevant data

Comment: there is no need .thanks to both of you friends I managed to find the solution.

Comment: first of all it is a subset selection problem. Then there is also a problem with the use of dateRangeInput.                                                                                                               
`myturkat <- reactive({turkat[turkat$time>=input$time[1] & turkat$time<=input$time[2],] })`                                                                         
 this solved my problem.